# Divisibility conditions

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, divisibility, principal-ideal-domains

A first part of a question on a practice exam asks whether there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ap + bn = 1$, where $p$ and $n$ are integers such that $p$ does not divide $n$, and $p$ is prime.

So $gcd(p,n) = 1$, and so we can write $p =  nq_1 + r_1$ where $r \neq 0$, then $n = q_2r_1 + r_2$, and carrying out the euclidean algorithm the procecess terminates at remainder $1$ and we can write it out backward.

I am then asked whether there are solutions $h,k \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $hf + kg = 1$ where $f$ is irreducible and does not divide g. I think that the division algorithm for polynomials would extend a similar argument here.

I am then asked the same question but considering $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ instead of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, and I'm not sure where to proceed. I only understand that the ideals of this are not principal, but I'm not sure how to say that the division algorithm wouldn't apply here.

Comment: "Where $p$ and $n$ are integers such that $p$ does not divide $n$"  That will depend heavily on the values of $p$ and $n$.  $4$ does not divide evenly into $6$ for example, but $4a+6b$ is always even and cannot equal $1$ for any choice of integers $a,b$.  You need a stronger condition... namely that $p$ and $n$ are coprime, i.e. $\gcd(p,n)=1$.

Comment: Perhaps you are missing the very important statement that not only must $p$ not divide into $n$ but also that $p$ must be prime...

Comment: I'm sorry, I left out a condition from the question which is very important which is that $p$ is prime

Comment: If $f$ is irreducible and does not divide $g$, you can conclude $\gcd(f,g)=1$

Comment: @blanchey In that case, the first claim is valid as well because then $p$ and $n$ must be coprime.

Comment: @Peter yes, I am much more comfortable with the first two parts of the question, however am still unsure of how to proceed with the last where they are polynomials in x and y and showing there is not necessarily a solution. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: In the two variable case, if you take the pair of elements $x,y$ and let $A$ be the (smallest) ideal they generate, does $A$ contain any constants?

Comment: @WillJagy That is the counterexample I was looking for. Thank you.